# PHP IMAP is not working after 30 May 2022

Tags: php, email, google-apps-script, gmail, imap

I have an application where I am retrieving the Gmail mail via IMAP but after the new policy of Google(30 May 2022), it's not working.

It's showing the error "imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX"
Previously it's working fine. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en has suggestions

Comment: Are you trying to use OAuth2 to access the mailbox, or have you created an App Password?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @droopsnoot I'd guess neither, given the date it stopped working :-)

Comment: This is the code where i am getting error. $connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'email@gmail.com', 'password') or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error()); and I can't use the 2 step verification. If I add 2 step verification then PHP will not allow me to login by code

Comment: You have to create an App Password as well, and use that in your code. Did you actually read the link I provided? There's then a link to this guidance explaining exactly what to do in the app password scenario: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: P.S. Never put big chunks of code in the comments of a question. As you can see it's not very readable. Your question has an [edit] button which you can use when you need to add more information - anything more than just a very brief comment in response, should be added to your question. And code etc can be formatted correctly. See also [ask] and related help centre articles. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [turn on 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en) and then use [App passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) to generate a new password for your app.

Comment: This is the code where i am getting error.

$connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'email@gmail.com', 'password') or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

and I can't use the 2 step verification. If I add 2 step verification then PHP will not allow me to login by code.

Comment: Have you tried it? because I'm using it in my app and It works for me.

Comment: Instead of the password that I use for login in Gmail, I'm using the App password, which works like before.

Comment: You enable 2-step verification on your desktop PC, go through the process, then create the app password, Use the app password to sign into the server just like you use 'password' now. The 2-step verification is not done through your application. I've just been through the same issue (which actually failed on June 5th for me), was concerned about how long it would take, and it took about five minutes and required no code changes.