# Gmail Email Inbox using PHP with IMAP after 30 May 2022

Tags: php, gmail, imap

Good day everybody,

I hope that someone can help me here... I'm trying to retrieve my mails via PHP script... I used the following script as a template:
[https://phppot.com/php/gmail-email-inbox-using-php-with-imap/][1]

In addition, I activated IMAP in the Google settings, activated two-factor authentication and created an app password.

I then uploaded the whole script to my server (IMAP is activated in php.ini)... but I still get the message:

> Cannot connect to Gmail: Can't connect to imap.gmail.com,993:
> Connection refused

I also tried the following:

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX and
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX
```

I would be happy if I got an answer :)

Comment: This probably answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72571339/7972413

Comment: Check your firewall settings.  Connection refused means either the server is down (unlikely) or something is blocking your connection.  For example many corporate networks block IMAP by default.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/72571339/7972413 unfortunately does not help... I have already implemented all the suggestions made there.

A firewall is also not active at the server hoster :/

Comment: Try using SSH directly on the server itself to [talk to the remote server using OpenSSL](https://serverfault.com/a/869305). If that can’t connect either you can rule out PHP. There’s a chance your host is just blocked by Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'Your Gmail Username', 'Your Gmail Password')
```

Note: Check these before check

1. Open your "Gmail".
2. In the top right, click "Settings" and then See "all settings".
3. Click the "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" tab.
4. In the "IMAP access" section, select "Enable IMAP".
5. Click "Save Changes".

Also check [this Article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en#zippy=)

Answer (score 0):

On your Google Account -> Security page is switch "Less secure app access".

It has to be ON to use PHP imap with username and password.

It turns automatically off if you don't use this kind of access for a month.